# UIToolbar at the bottom of container view

Tags: ios, uiview, uitoolbar, parallax, xcode-storyboard

I'm making an app with parallax effect. For this I use `QMBParallaxScrollViewController`, and created two child views.

What I need is to have the `UIToolbar` at the bottom of the view, so the user can scroll but always have the bar.

If I use it in the scroll detail child view, it is at the bottom of the scroll. I put it in the detail view controller root view, when the child view enter to the container, the bar is behind.

What can I do to have it at the bottom and the front?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer

It's not necessary to add the toolbar. A navigation controller have it by default, but hidden. To show it:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```